# Iterate over a type level list and call a function based on each type in the list

Tags: haskell, types

Given a list of types

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

type MyTypes = '[String, Int, Char]
```

and a type class similar to the following:

```
class MyClass a where
  describe :: Proxy a -> String

instance MyClass String where
  describe _ = "a String is a String"

instance MyClass Int where
  describe _ = "an Int represents a number"

instance MyClass Char where
  describe _ = "a Char represents a single character"
```

How can I iterate over `MyTypes` and call `describe` on each type that's in the list (provided that for each type in the list there's an instance of `MyClass`)?

I think I want something like `fmap` or `traverse` that builds a bridge between the type level and the value level.
For the list of types above, the result I'm after would be `["a String is a String", "an Int represents a number", "a Char represents a single character"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to emulate higher-order functions at the type-level can be quite complex. A more ad hoc answer is to make a class to map over a list with `describe`.

```
import Data.Kind (Type)

class MapMyClass (as :: [Type]) where
  mapDescribe :: Proxy as -> [String]

instance MapMyClass '[] where
  mapDescribe _ = []

instance (MyClass a, MapMyClass as) => MapMyClass (a ': as) where
  mapDescribe as = describe (headProxy as) : mapDescribe (tailProxy as)

headProxy :: Proxy (a ': as) -> Proxy a
headProxy _ = Proxy

tailProxy :: Proxy (a ': as) -> Proxy as
tailProxy _ = Proxy
```

Comment: This is very helpful, because it's indeed more pragmatic than what I asked for, which makes it more practical. What would you recommend if I wanted to abstract over `describe`(and later maybe even over the fact that it returns a list, any monad could be sufficient)? So something like `mapDescribe :: Proxy as -> (Proxy a -> b) -> [b]`.

Comment: I get a step closer with `mapDescribe :: (Monad m, Monoid b) => Proxy as -> (forall a. Proxy a -> m b) -> m b`, but this means that the function I'm passing can't have any extra constraints on the `a` (like a `Show` instance or anything). I might be asking too much from the compiler here?

Comment: `mapDescribe :: Proxy as -> (forall a. MyClass a => Proxy a -> b) -> [b]`

Comment: That's the way I went with for now, the only downside is that I can't reuse it for different constraints (`MyClass2` instead of `MyClass`). I just added a second function to `MapMyClass` with the other constraint, that's fine for now

Answer (score 1):

The [sop-core](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core) package provides useful functions to deal with type-level lists and values constructed from—or indexed by—them. In particular the [`Data.SOP.NP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html) module is focused on n-ary products (think tuples of various sizes were each component is wrapped in a functor).

```
import Data.SOP ( K(..) )
import Data.SOP.NP ( NP, collapse_NP, cpure_NP )
```

First, we use [`cpure_NP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:cpure_NP) to get an homogeneous (because parameterized by a constant functor [`K`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-BasicFunctors.html#t:K)) n-ary product containing the `describe` values:

```
descriptions :: NP (K String) MyTypes
descriptions = cpure_NP (Proxy @MyClass) d
    where
    -- The type signature here is to be able to refer to `a` in the Proxy.
    -- Because we are using a constant functor, we don't really have an `a` value,
    -- only a String.
    d :: forall a. MyClass a => K String a
    d = K (describe (Proxy @a))
```

The `c-` in `cpure_NP` is a notational convention. It means "function that assumes that [some constraint holds](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-Constraint.html#t:All) for all elements of a type-level list, and we supply that constraint by means of a `Proxy`".

Because the product is homogeneous, we can then use [`collapse_NP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:collapse_NP) to convert it to a normal list:

```
descriptionList :: [String]
descriptionList = 
    collapse_NP descriptions
```

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzymjoHC0ig) might be relevant.